# Python 3: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prompt' when launching from git bash

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, git-bash, prompt-toolkit

I have a python 3 application that uses the [prompt_toolkit](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library. If I launch the application through **cmd** or **PowerShell**, the application launches without an issue. However, when I launch the application through **Windows git bash**, I get the following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 313, in <module>
    ret_code = main(str(args.com))
  File "application.py", line 170, in main
    s_opt = session.prompt(f"{s_time} >")
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prompt'
```

Any reason why this is failing on git bash and not on cmd/PowerShell and is there a way to overcome this issue so that I can run my application from git bash?

I am using Python v3.8.3, prompt-toolkit v3.0.5, and git bash v2.26.2.windows.1, running on Windows 10.

Comment: I think it dosen't support git bash, I have also tried running some prompt-toolkit code in JetBrain's IDE and it gives a error similar to this